# Error InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index' when trying to add item to listview -- VB

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

Whenever I try to run the following code to insert a single row into my `listview` I get the error `"InvalidArgument=Value of '1' is not valid for 'index'"....`

```
            Dim item As New ListViewItem
            With item
                .SubItems(0).Text = CStr(newTri.nextTriID)
                .SubItems(1).Text = CStr(newTri.sideOne)
                .SubItems(2).Text = CStr(newTri.sideTwo)
                .SubItems(3).Text = CStr(newTri.sideThree)
            End With
            lstTris.Items.Add(item)
```

My `listview` has columns - TriangleID, SideOne, SideTwo and SideThree specified for it, and I am trying to add the items above to each respective column for each triangle user creates but I'm not sure why it is giving me an error?

Comment: YOu can do `lw.Items.Add(CStr(newTri.nextTriID)).SubItems.AddRange(CStr(newTri.sideOne), CStr(newTri.sideTwo), CStr(newTri.sideThree))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `ListView` has columns the `ListViewItem` itself doesn't automatically gain these columns.  Instead you have to add them one at a time.  Change the last 3 uses of `.SubItems` to the following

```
.SubItems.Add(CStr(newTri.sideOne))
.SubItems.Add(CStr(newTri.sideTwo))
.SubItems.Add(CStr(newTri.sideThree))
```

The first one which uses `0` doesn't need to be changed because it's automatically created as a part of creating the `ListViewItem`

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find anything so clearly explained like this.